# Video Proof: Why do I get the CloudFlare 1020 ERROR when I'm running my bot?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, cloudflare, botdetect

this is my first post and I'm facing a though problem since weeks. I developed an account creation bot with python to sign up accounts on a resell platform 24/7.

**https://youtu.be/jOxEtLjROLI** <- Here you can see what the bot does

At around **24 min** it gets blocked by CloudFlare and I receive the 1020 ERROR.

What I've tried to solve this problem so far:

- rotating residential proxies (proxyrack and hydraproxy)
- rotating user agents
- undetected chromedriver
- pauses in between (10-15 minutes)
- tor browser instead of chrome
- decrease the amount of created accounts to 2-5 accounts per hour.

But unfortunately nothing worked. I still get detected

This is my code:

```
def accountcreate():


for i in range(aa,500):
list_user_agents = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0']
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
userAgent = random.choice(list_user_agents)
print(userAgent)

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--lang=en")
options.add_extension('anticapt.zip')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(hostname + ":" + port))
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.web/")
```

If you need me to provide more from my script just let me know

Thank you very much for every kind of help!

Best regards

Comment: Please refine indentation to make the code readable.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the site has Rate Limiting enabled. Depending on the logic they have in place, your IP address would be blocked from anywhere between 15mins to 1hour. It's not something to do with your code - it's just a security mechanism specifically put in place to prevent this kind of action.

[This](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001635128-Configuring-Cloudflare-Rate-Limiting) page explain how it works. And [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-1020-access-denied/66439) gives more information about Error 1020 from Cloudflare.

You could probably try one request per hour or keep changing your IP address for each request.